# Conditional repetitive cumulative sums on python

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I need to write code on python that computes cumulative sums from an axis of an array but every certain number of elements (for instance 200), the idea is that I want to add up error deviation but for the last 200 time step over an array of 10000, considering the first 200 time step as initial conditions of zero. The whole computation represents the **integration** with a time of step = 1 but coniders only the last 200-time step.

in other words, I want the cumulative sum (of the last 200 elements) just every time, 200 counts have passed to be saved in a new array.

An example on a small scale for illustration

x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

consider summation every 2 counts and not 200

Result

y=[0,0,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17]

as you notice, nothing has been counted the first 2 counts, because they should be initialized with zero, only when 2 counts have passed and we become 10 elements back as well equivalent to the given array.

Can anybody help me with doing this in Python ,if possible with numpy?

Comment: Interesting problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please can you show an example of input and expected output to help clarify your question. You could use 10 instead of 200 to illustrate what you mean.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a community where we help each other learn how to program. We expect you to put some effort into attempting to solve the problem. We are not a code writing service. For more tips on improving your question to get the help you need, see [ask].

Comment: I added an example for illustration

Comment: `y` is just the cumsum of `x` with the two first elements masked. So take your 200+ elements array, calculated the cumsum and put it in another array, then put 0 or whatever in the 200 first elements.

Comment: @Guimoute that's the idea, how then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not compute cumulative sum to compute a sum over a running window

```
cx=x.cumsum()
y=cx[step:] - cx[:-step]
```

Comment: That is what I want